# Using SFINAE to check for member function and call it

Tags: c++, c++17, sfinae

I am trying to understand how SFINAE works.

My needs:

I have a set of types which may provide or not a member function called `activate`. The thing is if `activate` does exist for the given type, it may accept any arguments. I want to write a function that will forward to the type's `activate`, if it exists, otherwise simply `return true`.

I tried:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <functional>

struct A
{
    bool activate()
    {   
        std::clog << "A::activate() called" << std::endl;
        return true;
    }   

    bool activate(const char*)
    {   
        std::clog << "A::activate(const char*) called" << std::endl;
        return true;
    }   
};

struct B
{
    // NOTHING
};

template<class S, class... ARGS>
auto activate(S& s, ARGS&&... p_args) -> typename std::invoke_result<decltype(&S::activate)(S, ARGS...)>::type
{
    return s.activate(std::forward<ARGS>(p_args)...);
}

bool activate(...)
{
    return true;
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    A a;
    B b;

    activate(a);
    activate(a, "Hello");
    activate(b);

    return 0;
}
```

But nothing is ever printed. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
template<class S, class... ARGS>
auto activate(S& s, ARGS&&... p_args)
    -> typename std::invoke_result<decltype(&S::activate)(S, ARGS...)>::type
//                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

If `activate` is an overloaded member function, as it is for `A`, you can't take its address via `decltype`. Secondly, that's an incorrect use of [`invoke_result`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of) - it doesn't use the `result_of` syntax of `F(Args...)`, you just do `invoke_result<F, Args...>`. It's simpler.

What you want is to just directly invoke it yourself:

```
template<class S, class... ARGS>
auto activate(S& s, ARGS&&... p_args)
    -> decltype(s.activate(std::forward<ARGS>(p_args)...))
```

This side-steps the question of overloaded names, and how to use `invoke_result`.

Comment: Funny how after ten reads on cppreference I still did not see `invoke_result` does not have the same syntax as `result_of`. And yeah, for the address, it makes sense. Thank you.